# How to transform matrix-style dataframe into a collapsed table?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r that looks like this:

```
        AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1  AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1  AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1
GENE_X                   3                   1                   6
GENE_Y                   2                   0                   0
```

How can I format this into an output that looks more like this:

```
AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1  GENE_X  3
AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1  GENE_X  1
AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1  GENE_X  6
AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG-1  GENE_Y  2
AAACCCAGTATACCTG-1  GENE_Y  0
AAACCCAGTCGTACTA-1  GENE_Y  0
```

I tried using this kind of approach, but ran into memory errors (because in my actual dataframe, I have way more columns than in the example above). Is there a more memory-sensitive approach?

```
data.frame(rows=rownames(m1)[row(m1)], vars=colnames(m1)[col(m1)], values=c(m1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` in `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("var1") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-var1, names_to = "var2", values_to = "var3")

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   var1   var2                var3
#   <chr>  <chr>              <int>
# 1 GENE_X AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1     3
# 2 GENE_X AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1     1
# 3 GENE_X AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1     6
# 4 GENE_Y AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1     2
# 5 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1     0
# 6 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1     0
```

---

Base R solution:

```
setNames(cbind(row.names(df), stack(df)[2:1]), c("var1", "var2", "var3"))

#     var1               var2 var3
# 1 GENE_X AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1    3
# 2 GENE_Y AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1    2
# 3 GENE_X AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1    1
# 4 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1    0
# 5 GENE_X AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1    6
# 6 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can also convert the `matrix` to `data.frame` after adding the `table` attribute and this would reshape it with the dimnames attribute as two columns along with values as 'Freq' in the third column

```
as.data.frame.table(m1)
#     Var1               Var2 Freq
#1 GENE_X AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1    3
#2 GENE_Y AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1    2
#3 GENE_X AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1    1
#4 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1    0
#5 GENE_X AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1    6
#6 GENE_Y AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1    0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("GENE_X", "GENE_Y"), c("AAACCCAAGCTCAGAG.1", "AAACCCAGTATACCTG.1", 
    "AAACCCAGTCGTACTA.1")))
```